# Ubuntu in 3NStar Windows Tablet PC

Tags: system-installation

I have a question about the installation of Ubuntu in a Windows tablet.

The tablet's brand is 3NStar, anyone knows how is the installation procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are putting it on a tablet, I assume you are interested in Ubuntu touch. At the moment there are very few supported devices, and yours is not in the list. I also cannot see any community driven ports to your device on the [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices). If you want you can start your own community driven port for your device following their [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).